# Will I get performance boost combining concurrent.futures with Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, concurrent.futures

I'm wondering if it's OK to use `concurrent.futures` with Flask. Here's an example.

```
import requests
from flask import Flask
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/path/<xxx>")
def hello(xxx):
    f = executor.submit(task, xxx)
    return "OK"

def task():
    resp = requests.get("some_url")
    # save to mongodb

app.run()
```

The task is IO-bound and return value is not needed. Requests won't come frequently, I guess 10/s at most.

I tested it and it worked. What I want to know is whether I can get **performance boost** using multithreading this way. Will Flask block the task in some way?

Comment: If you have unfrequent I/O bound request you might be better off using a webserver with the reactor pattern line tornado or a library like twisted. This isn't the typical use case for flask.

Comment: I'm trying to make a decision if I should use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is dependent on more factors than Flask, like what you are using in front of Flask (gunicorn, gevent, uwsgi, nginx, etc). If you find that your request to "some_url" is indeed a bottleneck, pushing it to another thread might provide a boost, but again that depends on your individual circumstances; many elements in a web stack can make the process "slow".

Instead of multithreading on the Flask process (which can quickly get complicated), pushing blocking I/O to a helper process might be a better solution. You can send Redis messages to a process running on an asyncio event loop, which will scale well.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import redis

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    # send your message to the other process with redis
    r.publish('some-channel', 'some data')
    return "OK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=4000, debug=True)
```

helper.py

```
import asyncio
import asyncio_redis
import aiohttp

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_page():
    # get some url
    req = yield from aiohttp.get('http://example.com')
    data = yield from req.read()

    # insert into mongo using Motor or some other async DBAPI
    #yield from insert_into_database(data) 

@asyncio.coroutine
def run():
    # Create connection
    connection = yield from asyncio_redis.Connection.create(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)

    # Create subscriber.
    subscriber = yield from connection.start_subscribe()

    # Subscribe to channel.
    yield from subscriber.subscribe([ 'some-channel' ])

    # Inside a while loop, wait for incoming events.
    while True:
        reply = yield from subscriber.next_published()
        print('Received: ', repr(reply.value), 'on channel', reply.channel)
        yield from get_page()

    # When finished, close the connection.
    connection.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
```